# HTML not serving images in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm building a simple Django website but the image in my html file doesn't load, it is the same for any image inserted in the html page or the background image.

My settings.py file is as follows:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)    

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Site.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'SiteDatabase',
        'USER': 'siteadmin',
        'PASSWORD': 'siteadmin',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC+05:30'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#TEMPLATES

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates"),
)

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-files")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
    )
```

I've also updated my urls.py file as:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'qaengine.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                      document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The following is my static directory:

```
/static/

/static/images/home-background.jpeg

/static/media/

/static/static/home.css

/static/static-files/    (This is where all files from collectstatic are stored)

/static/templates/home.html
```

And the following are my html and css files:

HTML:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href = "../static/home.css" />
        </head>

        <body>
            <img src="../images/home-background.jpeg"/>
            <form method='POST' action=''>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}

                <input type='submit'>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../images/home-background.jpeg");
}
```

But the images doesn't load and I have no clue what's the problem in rendering it! Please help!

P.S. If I pull images from the internet that works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Have you tryed linking static resources this way?

```
<img src="{% static 'images/home-background.jpeg' %}" />
```

Django should replace `static` with your STATIC_URL, and the URL should became `/static/images/home-background.jpg`

**2)** You also need to add this at the beginning of you html file if you want to use `{% static ... %}`

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

**3)** When you use `{% static 'images/file.jpg' %}` you say that you want to replace static with the value of `STATIC_ROOT`.
In your settings.py you set `STATIC_ROOT` to `/static/static-files`.

I think that you can solve your problem setting properly STATIC_ROOT, making it point to /static/

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
```

Note that STATIC_ROOT is also the path of the folder where files from collectstatic are stored

Comment: It returns:


    `TemplateSyntaxError at /`

    `Invalid block tag: 'static'`

Comment: I've edited with new informations, i think that {% load staticfiles %} should work

Comment: The TemplateSyntaxError has been removed but the image is still not loading.

Comment: I have my media root as /static/media/

And media url as /media/

Comment: If you open the developer console on a browser (f12) does it tell you that there is a problem with the URL?

Comment: So as I understand it, `../images/` isn't taking me to `static/images/` and even if I hardcode it, it returns `not allowed to load local resource`

Comment: I've edited again. 
Does this URL works for you?
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/home-background.jpg

Comment: Have you tryed setting STATIC_ROOT?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the static path in your url:

```
body {
    background-image: url("/static/images/home-background.jpeg");
}
```

Or better yet,

```
body {
    background-image: url("{% static "/static/images/home-background.jpeg" %}");
}
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work...

And the static one returns

    `TemplateSyntaxError at /`

    `Invalid block tag: 'static'`

Comment: You must add `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of your template to make the `{% static ...%}` template tag available.

Comment: The TemplateSyntaxError has been removed but the images still won't load.